# How to convert an Array[Byte] to an Array[Int] in scala/spark?

Tags: arrays, scala

I have an `Array[Byte]` and I want to convert it to an `Array[Int]:`

for example,

```
val x : Array[Byte] = Array(192.toByte, 168.toByte, 1.toByte, 9.toByte)

val y : Array[Int] = Array(192, 168, 1, 9)
```

How can I convert x to y ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use simply map

```
val y:Array[Int] = x.map(_.toInt)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
val y = x.map(_.toInt)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it works:

```
val y = x.map(_.toInt & 0xff).deep
```

Comment: This will do and retain the values as they are I checked, but gives return type of `IndexedSeq[Any]` Can you please explian those `& 0xff` and `.deep`.  Arwa Z?

Comment: When I do simply `val y = x.map(_.toInt)` it returns `I@50930bff`, and when I do `val y = x.map(_.toInt).deep` it returns `Array(-64, -88, 1, 9)`. That is why I add `& 0xff` so the result is `Array(192, 168, 1, 9)`.